# After highlighting text in body of email it gets unselected

Tags: gmail, linux

When reading a post in Gmail if I highlight some text in the email body a split second later that highlighted text somehow reverts to being normal text not highlighted so I have to highlight same text again ( I am trying to copy text from Gmail post )

This happens across all browsers when reading Gmail

How to shut off this behavior ?

I am doing this highlight of text manually with the cursor nothing automated here ... this bad behavior in Gmail started a couple years ago however previously it was never an issue

Since it only happens in Gmail is this Google intentionally coding for this behaviour so perhaps some modification say a function rewrite could fix this ?

I am on a linux laptop ... current version of Ubuntu

**UPDATE**  issue seems to have gone away ... problem solved 20230720

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post but...

If you're using the Preview pane to read your messages, the message will be marked as read after 3 seconds.  When the message is marked as read, it deselects any text that is currently highlighted.

If you go into Gmail settings, on the General tab, you can change the setting named "Preview Pane:  Mark a conversation as read:" to "Immediately" and you won't have this problem again.